# Get the raw URL of an image in views-view-table.html.twig

Tags: views, 8

In the `views-view-table.html.twig` template, I can get the raw values of fields by repeating on `rows` and accessing the `view` object. For example:

```
    {{ view.field.title.value(view.result[i]) }}   {# the title of the node in this row #}
    {{ view.field.field_link.value(view.result[i]) }}   {# the URL in the link field #}
```

With `Formatter` for an image field set to `URL to image` in the view, I can test to see if an image exists in the field by doing:

```
    {% if view.field.field_image.value(view.result[i]) %}
```

QUESTION: How can I get the raw URL for the image? If I use:

```
    {{ view.field.field_image.value(view.result[i]) }}
```

I get a number as output. I have tried:

```
    {{ view.field.field_image.value(view.result[i]).entity.uri.value }}   {# I get nothing #}
```

and various combinations of things, but haven't hit the right one.

I know I don't have to use the raw values. For example, I can use

```
    {{ row.columns.field_image.content|render|striptags|trim }}
```

to get the URL, but this seems like a lot of processing to get something that must be available in the raw result.

Comment: Add `{{ dump(view.result) }}` to your template to get a dump of the content. You can then find the URL in there.

Comment: Thanks @Jaypan. The dump doesn't contain any URLs. For each row in the dump, the field_image array includes an alt field, a title field, some other fields, and notably a target_id field with integer value that is the same as when I insert {{view.field.field_image.value(view.result[i])}}. Clearly I need to use the target_id to get to the image URL, but I don't know how. I thought {{view.field.field_image.value(view.result[i]).entity.uri.value}} would do it, but it doesn't.

Comment: I get it. Your image is an entity reference. You will need to reference that entity. This: `{{ dump(view.result[0].entity) }}` should show you the values of the referenced entity.

Comment: Yes, I thought so too, but the output of `{{ dump(view.result[0].entity) }}` is NULL. It isn't that `view.result[0]` is an entity reference; isn't it that `view.field.field_image.value(view.result[0])` is an entity reference? Seems so, given that `{{ view.field.field_image.value(view.result[0]) }}` outputs what appears to be an entity number.

Comment: From the dump you got of `result[0]`, replace `target_id` with `entity` and dump that. Or you might need to appened `.entity` to it.

Comment: @MarshallMorrise are you using the [Image URL Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter) module?

Comment: You can also change the way the field is formatted in the view itself to output the url rather than a rendered image.

Comment: Thanks @Alfred Armstrong. I was already using the `URL to image format`. I mentioned that in my question, but maybe not clear enough.

Comment: @MarshallMorrise that's not what I meant. In the view you can choose to output the raw url as a text string. Then it's easier to manipulate in twig.

Comment: Thanks @Alfred Armstrong. I can try that. Do you mean by Rewrite Results, or is there another way?

Comment: Formatter: url to image, then you can use rewrite results to strip any wrapper html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all, especially @belltouche and @Jaypan, for taking the time to respond. After all the kind suggestions and lots of reading and trial-and-error, I ended up using the following code in `views-view-table.html.twig` to display an image URL:

```
{% for i, row in rows %}
  ...
  {% if view.field.field_image.value(view.result[i]) %}
    {{ row.columns.field_image.content|render|striptags|trim }}
  {% endif %}
  ...
{% endfor %}
```

Note that I'm using the `URL to image` formatter for the image field in the view.

To explain, `view.field.field_image.value(view.result[i])` gets the raw value of the image field, which turns out to be the entity id for the image. Checking it makes a concise test to see if there is an image in the field (if there's a better way, please say so).

It also turns out that there isn't any other information about the image in the raw value. Just the entity id, which is why I could never find the image URL in the raw value.

There was a suggestion made that I could use Twig Tweak to load the image entity by its id and get the URL from it. I'm sure this would have worked, but since my purpose was to avoid the overhead of `render|striptags|trim` processing, loading the entity after it had already been loaded to produce the content didn't seem an advantage.

Answer (score 0):

For a custom Views Field template, you can access entity field values in the row with a dot structured format with something looks something like this:
`row._entity.field_name.value` for the base entity, or `row._relationship_entities.field_name_that_brought_in_the_relationship.field_name_on_the_related_entity.value` when accessing something you brought in via Views' relationships. And I've gotten file uris with `file_url(...field_imagefieldname.entity.uri.value)`.

That being said, the comment about using `{{ dump(view.result) }}` is a good one.

Comment: Thanks @beltouche. I've tried every combination I can think of based on your suggestion and nothing has worked. I think it's because I'm in a Views Table template instead of a Views Field template, and I'm not using the `rows` variable, but am instead using the `views` variable to get raw values. I mention in my question the good results I get for simple fields using the `views` variable; just can't find the magic to get the raw value of the image URL.

Comment: Yes, this doesn't work like a field template. In Views you get either the finally rendered field content or the raw value, which is in your case the target id of the file or media entity. Core Twig doesn't have an option to load the entity, but you can use Twig Tweak to load the file/media entity and access their field values.